Trying to create a Digital Speedometer for a VehicleBody3D in GODOT 4
I am trying to create a digital speedometer (a number at the bottom of the screen) for my car in GODOT 4. When I run the game, the number in the label just keeps increasing, whether I speed up, slow down or am stopped.
My Node Tree looks like this:
World:
Car (Vehicle Body 3D)
Track 1 (Node)
Speedometer (Label)
Car:
Car-Body (Mesh Instance 3D)
Car-Body-Collider (Collision Shape 3D)
Front-Left-Wheel (Vehicle Wheel 3d):
Front-Left-Wheel-Mesh (Mesh Instance 3D)
Front-Right-Wheel (Vehicle Wheel 3d):
Front-Right-Wheel-Mesh (Mesh Instance 3D)
Back-Left-Wheel (Vehicle Wheel 3d):
Back-Left-Wheel-Mesh (Mesh Instance 3D)
Back-Right-Wheel (Vehicle Wheel 3d):
Back-Right-Wheel-Mesh (Mesh Instance 3D)
Track 1:
Mesh Instance 3D
This is my Script for the car, which is autoloaded:
extends VehicleBody3D

@export var TURN_SPEED = 0.2
@export var ENGINE_POWER = 250
@export var MAX_RPM = 10000
@export var MAX_TORQUE = 400

var _front_left_wheel
var _front_right_wheel
var _back_left_wheel
var _back_right_wheel

var _forwards_camera
var _backwards_camera
var _left_camera
var _right_camera

var speed


func _ready():
    _front_left_wheel = get_node("/root/World/Car/Front-Left-Wheel")
    _front_right_wheel = get_node("/root/World/Car/Front-Right-Wheel")
    _back_left_wheel = get_node("/root/World/Car/Back-Left-Wheel")
    _back_right_wheel = get_node("/root/World/Car/Back-Right-Wheel")
    
    _forwards_camera = get_node("/root/World/Car/Camera-Mount/Forwards-Camera")
    _backwards_camera = get_node("/root/World/Car/Camera-Mount/Backwards-Camera")
    _left_camera = get_node("/root/World/Car/Camera-Mount/Left-Camera")
    _right_camera = get_node("/root/World/Car/Camera-Mount/Right-Camera")

func _physics_process(delta):
    _move_and_rpm_and_sound(delta)
    _camera_switch()

    var speed = linear_velocity.length()
    print(speed)

func _move_and_rpm_and_sound(delta):
    steering = lerp(steering, Input.get_axis("right (turn)","left (turn)") * TURN_SPEED, 5 * delta)
    var acceleration = Input.get_axis("backwards","forwards")
    
    var rpm = _back_left_wheel.get_rpm()
    _back_left_wheel.engine_force = acceleration * MAX_TORQUE * (1 - (rpm / MAX_RPM))
    
    rpm = _back_right_wheel.get_rpm()
    _back_right_wheel.engine_force = acceleration * MAX_TORQUE * (1 - (rpm / MAX_RPM))
    
    rpm = _front_left_wheel.get_rpm()
    _front_left_wheel.engine_force = acceleration * MAX_TORQUE * (1 - (rpm / MAX_RPM))
    
    rpm =_front_right_wheel.get_rpm()
    _front_right_wheel.engine_force = acceleration * MAX_TORQUE * (1 - (rpm / MAX_RPM))
    
func _camera_switch():
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("forwards camera"):
        _forwards_camera.current = true
        
    elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("backwards camera"):
        _backwards_camera.current = true

    elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("left camera"):
        _left_camera.current = true
        
    elif Input.is_action_just_pressed("right camera"):
        _right_camera.current = true


This is my Script for the Speedometer:
extends Label

var speed : float

func _ready():
    text = "0 mph"

func _physics_process(_delta):
    speed = CarScrpt.speed
    speed *= 10
    
    text = str(int(speed)) + "mph"



It appears that you are never actually setting the speed variable within the Car script. Within the _physics_process(delta) method of the Car script, you declare a local speed variable every physics frame, but never assign that speed to the global speed variable of the Car script.
This can be fixed by removing the var keyword before setting the speed, causing the new line to look like:
speed = linear_velocity.length()

